If I am still happy now, "I am happy to talk to an old friend last week" an acceptable structure?
I talked to an old friend last week. Now I am still happy. Can I say,
Example 1

I am happy to talk to an old friend last week

or
Example 2

I am happy that I talked to an old friend last week.

or
Example 3

I am happy to have talked to an old friend last week


(1) is wrong. If you are happy to do something, you are willing to do it, so you can't use the expression of something you did last week.
(2) and (3) are OK.
